# Is a homogeneous symplectic isotopy always Hamiltonian?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

The following statements are written in the Guillermou-Kashiwara-Shapira's paper "Sheaf quantization of Hamiltonian isotopies and applications to non-displaceability".

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $I$ an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ containing the origin. Consider a homogeneous symplectic isotopy $\Phi:\dot{T}^*M\times I\rightarrow\dot{T}^*M$ where $\dot{T}^*M=T^*M-0_M$, that is, for each $t\in I$, $\phi_t=\Phi(\cdot,t)$ is a homogeneous symplectomorphism and $\phi_0=id_{\dot{T}^*M}$. Set $v_\Phi=\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial t}:\dot{T}^*M\times I\rightarrow T\dot{T}^*M$, $f=\alpha_M(v_\Phi):\dot{T}^*M\times I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $\alpha_M$ is the canonical Liouville 1-form of $\dot{T}^*M$ and $f_t=f(\cdot,t)$. Then $v_\Phi=X_{f_t}$ where $X_{f_t}$ is a Hamiltonian vector field in $\dot{T}^*M$.

In this statement, I cannot understand why the identity $v_\Phi=X_{f_t}$ holds. In particular, I don't know how to use the homogenity condition.

Answer (score 1):

From your other question:
[Any homogeneous symplectomorphism of tangent bundle $\dot{T}^*M=T^*M-0_M$ preserves the canonical Liouville form?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342767/any-homogeneous-symplectomorphism-of-tangent-bundle-dottm-tm-0-m-preser)
you know that a homogeneous symplectomorphism is exact:
$$ \forall t, \phi_t^* \alpha = \alpha. $$
Hence by differentiating with respect to t you get
$$\mathcal{L}_{X_t} \alpha = 0$$
where the vector field $X_t$ is defined by $(d/dt)\phi_t = X_t\circ \phi_t$.
By the Cartan formula, $\mathcal{L}_{X_t} \alpha = d(\iota_{X_t} \alpha) + \iota_{X_t}d\alpha$, and hence
$$ \iota_{X_t}d\alpha =  -d(\iota_{X_t} \alpha).$$
This means that $X_t$ is the hamiltonian vector field associated with the function $\iota_{X_t} \alpha$.